# How can I set a method of a Stub object to return 5 on the first call, and then 7 on the second call?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, stub

if you have an interface:

```
public interface ILuckynumberService
{
   int GetMyLuckyNumber();
}
```

And if you generate a stub for this interface like below, how can you enforce it to return 5 on the first call, then 7 on the second and 11 on the third call?

```
stubLuckyService = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ILuckyService>();
// Now, how to arrange stubLuckyService here?
```

Comment: it would be less statefull if `GetMyLuckyNumber` took a last number parameter that defaulted to k-1

Comment: Take it as an idiot proof example, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, although there may be a more straight forward way of doing it:

```
var results = new[] {5, 7, 11};
var count = 0;
service.Expect(x => x.GetMyLuckyNumber()).Return(0)
                                         .WhenCalled(x => { 
                                                x.ReturnValue = results[count];
                                                count++;
                                         });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
 int[] numbers = new[] {5, 7, 11};
 var cnt = 0;
 Func<int> numberToReturnFunc = () => { 
     var numberToReturn = numbers[cnt];
     cnt = cnt+1;
     return numberToReturn;
 }
 stubLuckyService.Stub(y => y.GetMyLuckyNumber()).Return(numberToReturnFunc());
```

I haven't tried it myself, but it could work. It compiles at least :).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Repeat.Once():

```
service.Expect(x => x.GetMyLuckyNumber()).Return(5).Repeat.Once();
service.Expect(x => x.GetMyLuckyNumber()).Return(7).Repeat.Once();
service.Expect(x => x.GetMyLuckyNumber()).Return(11).Repeat.Once();
```